# Heatmap and forest plot on the same pdf file

Tags: r

Is it possible to bind a heatmap derived from a `data.frame` and a forest plot derived from another data.frame (using ggplot2) in the same .pdf file so that the forest plot will be on the right side of the heatmap? Will the `par` function be sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give a complete answer without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D%20great%20reproducible%20example). However, one nice way to do it when you're using the `grid`-derived `ggplot2` package is with `viewport`s in `grid`:

First, define your plots without printing them:

```
heatmap <- ggplot(...
forestplot <- ggplot(...
```

Next, define viewports.

```
require(grid)
vp1 <- viewport(x=0.25, y=0.5, width=0.5, height=0.5)
vp2 <- viewport(x=0.75, y=0.5, width=0.5, height=0.5)
```

`x` and `y` represent the position of the center of the plot, along the x- and y-axes (from the left and bottom, respectively).

Then, use the `pdf` device to save the plot

```
pdf("my_file.pdf")
print(heatmap, vp=vp1)
print(forestplot, vp=vp2)
dev.off
```

Another possibility is to use `grid.arrange`, which will come up with a nice arrangement for you automatically:

```
require(gridExtra)
pdf("myfile.pdf")
grid.arrange(heatmap, forestplot)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Hi Drew! Thanks a lot and sorry but I have not an example...anyway your example is exactly what I need!!!! Thank you again!